# How to display html data in webview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display some html content data in webview. For displaying html data, i have one html file, but i dont know how to execute that html in webview. 
  Please guide me if any one knows.

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a too simple code and you will be limited very soon using it.
For example if you want to display images coming from your project bundle.

Prefer (if you use a HTML file) :

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

NSString* htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.htmlFilename ofType:@"htm"];
NSString* htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
if (error != nil) // Manage the error

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath]];
```

or shorter for direct HTML inline coding :

```
NSString* htmlContent = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body><img src='image.jpg' /></body></html>";
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the loadString method...

```
[webView loadHTMLString:myHtmlString baseURL:nil];
```