# UIWebView and Safari content not looking the same

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIWebView` which is adapted to a mobile style of a forum I have.  In Safari, it looks and works great.

However, inside my `WebView` there is a disastrous problem.

When quoting or editing a post, HTML is displayed inside of `BBcode`.  Furthermore, posting code results in ignored line breaks.

The webview is loaded like this:

```
  //display the webview
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.mysite.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webTest loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Share code how you load this in web view?

Comment: added code to original post

Answer (score 0):

Change your this line:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

With this line & check:

```
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Comment: still doesn't work but thanks for pointing out that unnecessary mutable request

Comment: NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.mysite.com"  [_webTest loadHTMLString:fullURL baseURL:nil]; Try with only these two lines...

Comment: This displays the url in the webview instead of loading it

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137378/how-to-display-html-data-in-webview-in-iphone

Comment: in this link see answer & look at: or shorter for direct HTML inline coding :

Comment: You also try with this method means statically load what you want in web view as describe in above link...

Comment: There is no file to load, everything is retrieved and parsed with php scripts on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load a html-string in your webView?

If it is the thing than following may help you:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath];

NSString *htmlString = [bundlePath pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"] ;
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: It's a forum, so all content is handled in the webview, no html is sent from the app itself.